# How to dynamically get MTM/TFS Test Case ID calling associated automation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

Right now our test base has 1:1 association in that for every Test Case on MTM/TFS - there is a C# test class that is associated to that test case only.

Within the test class the test case ID is hard coded as a value and that's how the data parameters are retrieved from the MTM/TFS Test Case to be executed at run time.

Unfortunately this has caused a lot of bloat and a lot of test cases that aren't much more than copy/pasted templates with the hardcoded test case Id being modified.

*Is there a way for a SINGLE C# TestClass to retrieve the data dynamically from the MTM/TFS Test Case that is associated with it? And therefore the ability to have many MTM/TFS Test Cases associated to that SINGLE C# Test Class?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get test case id from code within a test case class, you can get it from the TestContext instance. The following blog post gives you the list of a properties present in the class.

http://fluentbytes.com/switching-browser-in-codedui-or-selenium-tests-based-on-mtm-configuration/

The following code will give you the test case Id

```
var testCaseId = TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_TestCaseId__"].ToString()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Going to try this out and give best answer if it works, thanks!